# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'

Tags: android, cordova

I set android home environment variable like this

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/associate/Android/Sdk 
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

After run cordova requirements android --verbose it show

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29,android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21

Gradle: installed /home/associate/android-studio/gradle-5.1/bin/gradle

================ The error is ===============

After run sudo cordova build android command from under a cordova project, it show

Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need create ANDROID_HOME. In System variables, choose Path and click edit it. In Edit Environment variable click new and add path like : D:\folder_android_sdk\platform-tools and try again. Hope to help you